# Docusign API- disable tool tip in template fields?

Tags: docusignapi

Wasn't able to find this in the REST API guide or a related question. Currently it appears that tool tip text on hover is default behavior when working with a template. Is there a way to disable this en masse? I didn't see a config option in features as well. Just needed to confirm if this was configurable from the dashboard and/or able to be set as a tab parameter in the call. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to disable the tooltips altogether (i.e., via any Account-level setting or Resource file configuration setting). In an API request, it's the **name** property of each tab that enables you to specify a value for the tooltip of the tab -- so you might try experimenting with that property to see if it's possible to *blank-out* the tooltip for each individual field (although I've personally never had much luck with this approach).

Comment: Good to know the name property maps to the tooltip value. I tried saving the tooltip text as a blank value in the template config screen and it didn't persist; however, I may just wind up passing in a name value in the call to the field name on our end. Thanks.